# Beautiful soup replaces certain symbols in a URL with other symbols

Tags: web-scraping, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a certain webpage  with Beautiful soup, trying to retrieve all links that are inside h3 tag:

```
page = = requests.get(https://www....)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
links = []
for item in soup.find_all('h3'):
 links.append(item.a['href']
```

However, the links found are different than the links present in the page. For example, when the link http://www.estense.com/?p=116872 is present in the page, Beautiful soup returns http://www.estense.com/%3Fp%3D116872, replacing '?' with '%3F' and '=' with %3D. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: It's url escaping. But I cannot reproduce this issue. What version of Python do you use?

Comment: I use Python 3.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unquote the URL using `urllib.parse`

```
from urllib import parse
parse.unquote(item.a['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain the origin of this problem?

Comment: The reason could be that the link from the `<a href` is encoded, you will never know this when you view source because our browsers decodes the URLs automatically